# inserting data from a asp.net page to sqlserver database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

there are two tables in database.

one is `'books'` with 4 columns

```
pkid,title,price,writer(int)
```

and other is `'persons'` with columns

```
pkid, name,value(int).
```

one asp.net page is there with text boxes named

```
title,price,writer and a submit button.
```

i want that on filling that writer txtbox with some name which is available in `'persons'` table and clicking that submit button it will store integer `'value'` in `'books'`  writer column.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple.

- On your asp.net page, you can replace the *writer* textbox with a `DropDownList`
- [Populate the `DropDownList`](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sd_patel/dropdownlistbox11222005064123am/dropdownlistbox.aspx) with all of the persons available in your `Persons` table, when your page loads.
- On submit button click event,

  - [Make a connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32c5dh3b%28VS.71%29.aspx) to database
  - [Update the record](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx), with some [`update table set`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) like query.
- Reload the page with thanks!

But before all of this, I would suggest you go through [basic crud operations](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/The-Simplest-CRUD-Operations-for-Lookup-Tables-in-ASPNET/) using asp.net and how they are achieved. Here are some asp.net [quick start tutorials](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/data/default.aspx).